# Force Visual Studio to use only standard C++ and not to use platform specific things

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to write a cross-platform algorithm in C++ with Visual Studio 2013.

Unintentionally, one can use platform specific API functions (`_beginThread`, `strcpy_s` etc.) and when attempting to compile on Mac, results in errors.

Is there a way to force Visual Studio to not use platform-specific API (use only standard C++)?

Comment: Note that even if you can do that, you will still get compiler errors from time to time due to subtle differences in interpretation or the standard, or just plain nonconformance to the standard. As such the only proper remedy is to always build the latest code on all platforms, so that any errors are revealed as soon as possible. Some kind of build server can do that for you.

Comment: **You** shouldn't use platform-specific APIs. VS can't prevent you from doing that.

Comment: You could setup a custom build step that runs your code through GCC, but, as the others pointed out, the onus is pretty much on you.

Comment: I think what he means is can he get a compile-time warning on using platform specific functions and keywords.

Comment: @acraig5075 you can say yes. One can treat warnings as errors

Comment: @Anil8753 yes, one can. One can especially easily with gcc's `-Werror`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways you could do to achieve this.

1. Use the #ifdef directive.

   ```
   #ifdef _MSC_VER
   strcpy_s(str1, str2);
   #else
   strcpy(str1, str2);
   #endif
   ```
2. Create alias for `strcpy_s`.

   ```
   #ifdef _MSC_VER
   #define strcpy strcpy_s
   #endif
   ```
3. Add _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS and _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to C++ Preprocessor Definition in Visual Studio Project. Do this only if you're 100% sure about what you're doing and using platform agnostic code is fine.

Comment: This is not the answer for question. #ifdef approach is invalid. If MSCV injects 100K such api call, how many places we can put #ifdef.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer to include the aliasing approach. This aliasing code can be placed in a centralized location and all the `strcpy` in other places will be replaced with `strcpy_s`